# $n^2$ for bases to prove that the last digit of base b ends with 0

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider numbers written in base $b$, where $x\leq q\leq z$. For which bases $q$ $n^2$ ends with if $n$ ends with $0$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Considering bases for a numbers ending with 0](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336219/considering-bases-for-a-numbers-ending-with-0)  It is a duplicate, but this is the older one.  The wording is identical.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For any base $b$, things will go bad if there is a positive integers $x$ such that $x^2$ is divisible by $b$ but $x$ isn't. For example, $30^2$ is divisible by $50$ but $30$ isn't, so things will go bad for base $50$.

**Added:** Let us think about the specific bases $5$ to $9$. Let's see what we need to make sure that if $n^2$ ends in $0$, then $n$ ends in $0$.  To say that $n^2$ ends in $0$ is just to say that the base $b$ divides $n^2$. To say that $n$ ends in $0$ just says $b$ divides $n$.

So we ask for the various bases, when does $b$ divides $n^2$ **force** $b$ divides $n$?

Case $b=5$: If $5$ divides $n^2$, does $5$ divide $n$? Sure. After all, $5$ is prime.

Case $b=6$: If $6$ divides $n^2$, does $6$ divide $n$? If $6$ divides $n^2$, then $2$ divides $n^2$ and $3$ divides $n^2$. But then $2$ divides $n$ and $3$ divides $n$, so $6$ divides $n$.

Case $b=7$: same reasoning as for $5$: if $7$ divides $n^2$ then $7$ divides $n$.

Case $b=8$: This one is different. Let $n=4$. Then $8$ divides $n^2$ but $8$ does not divide $n$.

Case $b=9$: This is like $b=8$. Let $n=6$. Then $9$ divides $n^2$ but $9$ does not divide $n$.

**Generalization:** The "bad" bases $8$ and $9$ are each divisible by a perfect square greater than $1$. Call a positive integer $b$ **square-free** if no perfect square $\gt 1$ divides $b$. If $b$ is square-free, like $b=10$, then if $n^2$ in base $b$ ends in a $0$, then so does $n$.

If $b\gt 1$ is **not** square-free, there will be some $n$ such that in base $b$, the number $n^2$ ends in a $0$, but $n$ does not.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around your example. So how do is $30^2$ translated into a base 50?

Comment: Let's not worry about the details of the translation. We will want to express $30^2$ as $a_1\cdot 50^1+a_0$ where $a_1$ and $a_0$ are "digits." Since $50$ divides $300$, we will have $a_0=0$. I will add to my hint in about $10$ minutes, since you have been thinking about this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Note this example in hex.  You have `0x4`${}^2$ = `0x10`.  It's not in your range, but it should  tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider why this is true of base 10:

Ending in 0 means that a number is a multiple of 10.  Thus, its prime factorization includes 2*5.
How does squaring affect the prime factorization?