# Numbers ending with 0

Tags: arithmetic

$2n$ ends with $0$ if $n$ ends with $0$. So how can we know if 2n ended with 0 in the first place?

Comment: It's a good idea when you get answers that are helpful, to accept an answer. You can "accept" one answer per question (soon, with a little more reputation, you'll be able to "up-vote" as many answers as you'd like). To accept an answer, just click on the $\large \checkmark$ that appears to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It's one way to say "thanks"! Plus, you get two reputation points for each answer you accept.

Answer (score 3):

Try squaring all the single digit numbers in each base.  In some of them you will only find that $0^2$ ends in zero.  In others you will find a non-zero number that has a square ending in zero.  I would suggest you do bases 2 through 9, then think about what is special about the ones where you find a non-zero number with square ending in zero.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For $b=5$ we know a number ends in 0 when written in base 5 only when the number's remainder when divided by 5 is 0.
Now when $b=5$ if $n^2$ has remainder 0 when divided by 5, must $n$?

What is special about 5 that makes this work?

Answer (score 2):

For $b=9$, note that in base 9, $3^2=10$ for an easy counterexample.  Some of these are easy if you consider the prime factors of $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=a_0+a_1b+a_2b^2+\cdots+a_{r-1}b^{r-1}+a_rb^r$ in base $b$

So, $$n^2=(a_0+a_1b+a_2b^2+\cdots+a_{r-1}b^{r-1}+a_rb^r)^2$$
$$=a_0^2+2a_0a_1b+b^2(a_2^2+2a_0a_1)+2b^3(a_0a_3+a_1a_2)+\cdots+a_r^2b^{2r}$$

Now, $n^2$ and $n$ with end with same digit if $b$ divides $a_0^2-a_0=a_0(a_0-1)$

If $a_0=0, b$ always divides $a_0(a_0-1)$, hence $n^2$ will end with $0$ if $n$ ends with $0$

A little **generalization** :

Observe that $(a_0,a_0-1)=1$

If $b$ is prime like $5,7$ or power of prime like $2^3=8, 3^2=9$, so

either $b\mid a_0\implies a_0=0$ as $0\le a_0<b$

or $b\mid(a_0-1) \implies a_0=1$

If $b$ can be expressed as a product of two other numbers $p,q$ such that $p>q>1;(p,q)=1$ like $6$

either $(i)p\mid a_0, q\mid(a_0-1)$

or $(ii) q\mid a_0, p\mid(a_0-1)$

or $(iii) q\mid a_0(a_0-1)$

or $(ii) p\mid a_0(a_0-1)$

$(i),(ii)$ can be solved using [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html).